# Update each object in list in Java with the sum of internal values

Tags: java

I'm having a list of ContactDto objects. I'm having two fields in ContactDto  as value and totalValue. I want to have the sum of all values in totalValue. This totalValue should be same in all objects. Here is my code

```
ArrayList<ContactDto> l = new ArrayList<>();
    ContactDto c1 = new ContactDto();
    c1.setContact("SpecialContact");
    c1.setContactType("Phone");
    c1.setSlNo("1");
    c1.setValue(10);
    l.add(c1);
    ContactDto c2 = new ContactDto();
    c2.setContact("ContactSpecial");
    c2.setContactType("Email");
    c2.setSlNo("3");
    c2.setValue(20);
    l.add(c2);
    ContactDto c3 = new ContactDto();
    c3.setContact("NormalContact");
    c3.setContactType("Phone");
    c3.setSlNo("1");
    c3.setValue(30);
    l.add(c3);
    int totalValue = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        l.get(i).setTotalValue(l.get(i).getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(l);
```

### Output

What I receive is

```
[ContactDto [slNo=1, contact=SpecialContact, contactType=Phone, value=10, totalValue=10], ContactDto [slNo=3, contact=ContactSpecial, contactType=Email, value=20, totalValue=20], ContactDto [slNo=1, contact=NormalContact, contactType=Phone, value=30, totalValue=30]]
```

What I expect is

```
 [ContactDto [slNo=1, contact=SpecialContact, contactType=Phone, value=10, totalValue=60], ContactDto [slNo=3, contact=ContactSpecial, contactType=Email, value=20, totalValue=60], ContactDto [slNo=1, contact=NormalContact, contactType=Phone, value=30, totalValue=60]]
```

Comment: Do you have control over ConctactDto class definition?

Comment: `l.get(i).setTotalValue(l.get(i).getValue())` - what do you expect that to do?

Comment: Your requirement is strange here..it's not a good practice to store values(total values) like you want here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **first** have to iterate all objects to **sum** their values.

**Afterwards** you iterate the list again, and now you **set** that freshly computed total value.

In other words: you need *two* passes here. One to *compute* the total value, and another one to *update* your objects with that total value. That is all there is to this:

```
for(ContactDto dto : l) {
  totalValue += dto.getValue();
}

for(ContactDto dto : l) {
  dto.setTotalValue(totalValue);
}
```

And yes: you should use for-each looping - there is no point in using the overly complex index-based for loop here.

And beyond that: this solves the *question* asked. If this implementation is **really** making sense - is somehow doubtful. You see, this leads to **duplication** of information. And that is rarely a good thing. A "list total" should be a property of the *list*, not something that is reflected repeatedly for each object!

Comment: @Aliy this answer is correct but maybe it's not what you need. Think about why you want to store the total value inside each object in the first place. Shouldn't you be doing that in a view in SQL instead?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException You are correct; and I added another paragraph to make that more explicit!

Comment: @GhostCat one more comment about the OP's request: keeping a total inside each item means that every time an item is added to the list, all items have to be updated; so creating the list is an O(n²) operation.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the sum, you should keep it saved in the `totalValue` field, as :

```
for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    totalValue += l.get(i).getValue();
}
```

and then set the same value to all the elements in the arraylist -

```
for(int j=0;j<l.size(); j++) {
    l.get(j).setTotalValue(totalValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you..Missed that point. You have to iterate it again before l.get(i).setTotalValue(totalValue);

Comment: @GhostCat Ya, strange though. Had to set the totalValue same in all the elements. Updated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, and that is actually ... a strange requirement. The fact that you got that wrong is a *clear hint* that the whole question is ... well, strange.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    l.get(i).setTotalValue(l.get(i).getValue());
}
```

Here you're setting to every object the total value to the value of that object, and not the total value. What you need to do is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    totalValue = totalValue + l.get(i).getValue();
}

for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    l.get(i).setTotalValue(totalValue);
}
```

And that should do your job.
You need to first sum all values to get totalValue and then to set totalValue to each object in list.